# How to escape special charater in javascript's Variable

Tags: javascript

I might asking a naive question.
But I am stuck. My requirement is do masking of data.

Following is the code snippet :

```
var str = substr(Test_dat,0,6);
var Test_dat1 = replace(Test_dat,str,"SampleSample");
```

So basically, "Test_dat" is input string and I am applying substr() function the on incoming data. And then replacing based on masking logic.

If

```
var Test_dat = "Vikas(vikas)";
var str = substr(Test_dat,0,5);
var Test_dat1 = replace(Test_dat,str,"SampleSample");
```

Output

```
SampleSample(vikas)
```

If
Input

```
var Test_dat = "Vikas(vikas)";
var str = substr(Test_dat,0,6);
var Test_dat1 = replace(Test_dat,str,"SampleSample");
```

Error Message

```
Function call replace is not valid : Unclosed group near index 6
```

I know it's because of '(' but I am not able to understand how to escape in variable "str".

Any Help!!

Comment: `substr` and `replace` are not global functions in Javascript. Unclear what this code is supposed to be doing…

Comment: You do some very weird stuff. `substr` and `replace` are string functions... Here it seems it's not those functions you call. What are you doing actually?

Comment: you an use `\\` to escape special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you use `substr` and `replace`. This code works well.

```
var Test_dat = "Vikas(vikas)";
var str = Test_dat.substr(0,6);
var Test_dat1 = Test_dat.replace(str,"SampleSample");
```

Comment: Right, that's why I deleted mine after you changed this (and I'll delete these remaining soon)